# Selenium fails to scroll down on this website

Tags: python, selenium

I want to scroll down multiple times until all the team matches are fully loaded. I am trying with the code below,

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("https://www.betpawa.ke/upcoming")

eles = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='teams']")

while len(eles)<300:
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(3)
browser.close()
```

Strangely, if I run it, it does not scroll... it seems the javascript code does not work on the website because I have tried without the while loop and still nothing happens. Is there a work around or am I doing something wrong..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why scrolling is not working here, but I do see that your loop will be endless since you do not update the `eles` list so it will stay with it's initial state forever.
To fix that try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("https://www.betpawa.ke/upcoming")

eles = set()

eles.update(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='teams']"))

while len(eles)<300:
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    eles.update(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='teams']"))
time.sleep(3)
browser.close()
```

I have defined `eles` as set so it will add a new elements only each time you are scrolling the page.
As about the scrolling itself, again, I see no problem. It should work.

Comment: Just tried the code.... it still doesn't scroll down page